# How to split the string in array in php

Tags: php

Can you tell me how i can split the below string in respective array

Here is the string:

```
ujjwal;23
33334;14
pendrive;20
```

Now I want to put above string into array like this:

```
array([0]=>ujjwal,[1]=>33334,[2]=>pendrive)
```

ignoring the number or string after semi-colon `;` , please help me

Comment: Are you expecting [this](https://eval.in/641852)? What is your try?

Comment: Is there line break in each line ? or single line ?

Comment: yes line break in each line and i'm expecting this

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) PHP function to split the string by `;`.

First you need to split the string by `\n` and then iterate over line by line and split by `;`.  And append the first element of the array in final array.

Code would look something like this,

```
<?php

$str="ujjwal;23
33334;14
pendrive;20";

$lines=explode("\n",$str);
$farray=array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $linearray=explode(";",$line);
    $farray[]=$linearray[0];
}
print_r($farray);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/641849

Comment: Great, please accept it as correct answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming thats in a file?

```
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $elements = explode(';', $line);
    $array[] = $elements[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$new_array = array();
$string = "ujjwal;23 33334;14 pendrive;20";
// if string is not in single line then use explode("\n",$string );
$temp_array = explode(" ",$string);
foreach($temp_array as $val)
{
    $new_array[] = strtok($val, ';');
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ujjwal
    [1] => 33334
    [2] => pendrive
)
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/g0kcM)**